# Why does parsing a date on some devices throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: date, datetime, java-me, codenameone

I have the following string, representing a date and time, that's ISO 8601 compliant:

> 2014-03-11T11:57:15+0000

I'm using the Codename One SimpleDateFormat class to parse that string in to a Date object and then to populate a Calendar object:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DateTimeFormats.ISO_8601);
Date date = format.parse("2014-03-11T11:57:15+0000");
calendar.setTime(date);
```

DateFormats.ISO_8601 is defined as

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

On the Codename One simulator this code correctly parses the string and sets date with the correct values.  This also works on a Nokia C1-01.  However, running the same code on a Nokia 206 or the DefaultCldcPhone1 emulator from the Java ME SDK results in an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception on the call to format.parse.  The stack trace beyond that is obfuscated:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
- java.util.Calendar.get(), bci=98
- al.a(), bci=3
- al.a(), bci=18
- al.parse(), bci=1013
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, how I can prevent it, or suggest a work-around for populating a Calendar from a string without having to write my own parser?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using the `com.codename1.l10n.SimpleDateFormat` class instead of the one from the `java.text` package. This will allow you to reproduce the issue on the simulator and debug it more accurately.